# Чем отличается запятая от точки в double?

Tags: c++

Когда я с клавиатуры ввожу 328,1, я получаю ответ: 99.9696, а если ввожу 328.1, то все нормально. В чем разница между точкой и запятой?

```
double f, m;
cout << "Введите длину(в футах): ";
cin >> f;
m = f / 3.281;
cout << f << " футов = " << m << " метров\n";
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Разница в том, что если не принять специальные меры, чтоб запятая считалась разделителем целой и дробной частей числа. Стандартно таковым в С++ является точка.

Так что когда вы вводите 328,1 - считывается только 328, затем идет запятая, которой в числе быть не может, так что на этом чтение завершается, и `f` принимает значение 328.

Кстати, при этом в буфере ввода остается запятая, так что если бы вы написали далее еще один оператор чтения числа - то он бы просто не работал, переведя при этом поток `cin` в состояние `fail`.

Comment: стандартно - разделитель зависит от локали.

Comment: @Croessmah Это я и имею в виду под "специальными мерами". Но, мне кажется, человеку, который задает такой вопрос, еще рано забивать голову локалями...

Comment: полностью согласен.